# I can't switch to NVIDIA GPU

Tags: nvidia, graphics, intel, gpu

I want to use NVIDIA GPU, but I can't.
I installed the proper driver and checked `NVIDIA (Performance Mode)` from the NVIDIA Settings app.
I tried to switch to NVIDIA through `prime-select` command, but when I checked the active GPU from Settings > About or `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"` command, I still saw Intel.